# .htaccess page rerouting - getting 404

Tags: url-rewriting

I'd like to use my `.htaccess` file to ensure that the following routing will happen:

> success_stories.php --> success_storie

Here is what I've tried, but it is not working, as I get a 404.

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^success_stories.php$ /success_storie [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: it's only example , give me solution ,i don't need grammar mistakes or corrections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that

```
## hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```